# NotSerializableException Exception while converting to InputStream

Tags: java, serialization, inputstream

When I convert array of bytes to Inputstream it gives NotSerializableException Exception. (Please refer code below)

```
// return type of myBO.getAttachedFile() is byte[]
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(myBO.getAttachedFile());
```

I have checked the return of method myBO.getAttachedFile() and it is serialize. So My problem is why it is NOT SERIALIZE after converting to InputStream as written in the code below. Return type of myBO.getAttachedFile() is byte[]

To check the serialization of myBO.getAttachedFile(), I have used the code below. It doesn't give exception

```
    try {
        new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()).writeObject(myBO.getAttachedFile());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("========EXCEPTION====== Object Not Serialized");
        logger.debug(METHOD_NAME, e);
    }
```

When I check the serialization for inputStream it gives exception in the code below

```
    try {
        new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()).writeObject(inputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("========EXCEPTION====== Object Not Serialized");
        logger.debug(METHOD_NAME, e);
    }
```

Comment: The code you've posted can't throw that exception unless there is a hidden deserialization somewhere you haven't shown us. The exception is `NotSerializableException,` not what it says in your title. Accuracy please. Post the exception, message, and stack trace. The part about serializing input streams doesn't begin to make sense, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: You've edited your question but you've only addressed the minor issues. You're not going to get an answer without a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to write a whole `InputStream` instance to `ObjectOutputStream`, instead of the contents of the actual resource it is internally referring to. You can only write instances which implement the [`Serializable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), otherwise you will get a rather self-explaining `NotSerializableException`.

The [`InputStream` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) does indeed **not** implement the `Serializable` interface. The `InputStream` instance represents merely a pointer to an opened byte resource on the underlying environment. On the contrary to the `byte[]` instance, the `InputStream` instance does by itself not contain any data which you'd like to serialize. The `InputStream` instance is merely a "messenger" between the actual byte resource on the underlying environment (e.g. a disk file system pointer) and the Java code. It is capable of reading the data as `byte`/`byte[]` and returning it, but it does by itself not store them anywhere in the instance. It has no `private byte[] alldata` property or so.

You really can't serialize such a thing. The resource would leak away (so, when you do this too often in a too short time, your environment will run out of resources) and the pointer is not necessarily valid anymore at the moment when you deserialize it, for sure not when you do it at a completely different environment.

Just use `byte[]`. Or, perhaps better, forget the whole serialization attempt. Depending on the concrete functional requirement, this is most likely not making any sense for whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: None of it makes sense. Exceptions that aren't thrown by the code that's posted; a redundant 'proof' that InputStream isn't serializable, which  we knew, and which doesn't appear to have anything to do with the real question; failure to post the real exception or the real code when asked. It's pointless.

Comment: @BalusC Not sure why your answer was downvoted. Let me rectify this ;)